# How to make filter on choice filed of lookup column in sharepoint REST API Odata Query

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest

I have two custom list client and transaction.

client list contain Status choice column.
Now client name is lookup column of Transaction list. I am trying to get using exapand ClientName Lookup column and make filter on it like below. But its throws Bad Request.

```
ClientName/Status+eq+Complete
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use REST query on status field, because the type of the field is choice. In SharePoint it's not allowed to create a lookup to point to the choice field, this is root cause of such behavior.

But hopefully it is possible to use lookup with calculated text column.

So you can workaround your issue by creating calculated column inside Client list, say `StatusCalc` with formula `=Status`. The main purpose of this field is simply showing the value of corresponding choice field.
Now you can use REST as following:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('temp')/items?$select=client/StatusCalc,Title,Id&$expand=client&$filter=client/StatusCalc+eq+'my choice'
```

Comment: i have tried  this still it give 400  Error Code. if i remove from filter then its work well

Comment: Right, you need to apply url encoding, I missed that. Updated answer

Comment: I have posted url that also not work

Comment: For multiple filters you need to use `and` keyword, instead of comma, ie `$filter=(StartDate ge datetime'2014-01-01T00:00:00Z') and (EndDate le datetime'2013-12-31T00:00:00Z')`

Comment: "and" for and operations and "or" for or :)